# WebView2 at 4K monitor is displayed incorrectly

Tags: c#, webview2

I have problem with my windows application, that i started to develop. After many issues with displaying correct visual at different dpi settings i came to state, that everywhere it is functional, except my friend's computer with 4K monitor.

Here is a screenshot of his instance > [image]

I have enabled PerMonitorV2 in app.manifest, tried all AutoScale setting for form, added gdiScaling to app.manifest...

Don't know how to solve this, any help?

I have tried almost everything, that i've googled.
I'm expecting help to solve displaying issues on 4K monitor with WebView2 component.

```
webView = new WebView2();  
webView.Visible = false;  
webView.Margin = new Padding(0);  
webView.Padding = new Padding(0);  
webView.Size = new Size(Width, 0);  
webView.AllowExternalDrop = false;  
webView.BackColor = BackgroundColor;  
webView.DefaultBackgroundColor = BackgroundColor;  
await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();  
webView.NavigateToString(text);

fContainer = new FlowLayoutPanel();  
fContainer.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;  
fContainer.Size = new Size(Width, Height - (fTitle.Bottom - fTitle.Top) - (fActions.Bottom - fActions.Top));  
fContainer.BackColor = ApplicationFramework.FORM_BACK_COLOR;  
fContainer.Padding = new Padding(0);  
fContainer.Margin = new Padding(0);  
fContainer.WrapContents = false;  
fContainer.AutoSize = false;  
fContainer.AutoScroll = false;  
fMain.Controls.Add(fContainer);  
  
fContent = new FlowLayoutPanel();  
fContent.BackColor = ApplicationFramework.FORM_BACK_COLOR;  
fContent.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;  
fContent.Size = new Size(Width - (HasMenu ?ApplicationFramework.MENU_WIDTH : 0), Height - (fTitle.Bottom - fTitle.Top) - (fActions.Bottom - fActions.Top));  
fContent.WrapContents = false;  
fContent.Padding = new Padding(0, ApplicationFramework.PADDING, 0, 0);  
fContent.Margin = new Padding(0);  
fContent.AutoScroll = true;  
  
fContent.Controls.Add(webView);
```

Here is the app.manifest :

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">  
    <windowsSettings>  
        <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>  
        <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2,PerMonitor</dpiAwareness> <!-- DpiUnawareGdiScaled -->  
        <gdiScaling xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2017/WindowsSettings">true</gdiScaling>  
    </windowsSettings>  
</application>
```

Comment: webview? are you sure this is c# problem and not css?

Comment: On my both laptops it is displayed correctly at all resolutions and font scaling when adjusted in windows settings ;)

Comment: Unsure what your last comment means here, but without any (relevant) code people aren't gonna be able to help you out. Please create a [mre]

Comment: we can't tell much without code. but by the look of how the boxes misaligned, all i could think off were css issue. absolute positioning tend to put stuff out of whack on larger/smaller screen.

Comment: I don't think so, there's no absolute positioning in html / css. The control is out of its normal position and is displayed through other controls in FlowLayoutPanel

Comment: Ok, i've added some code ;)

Comment: Ok, i found this problem at GitHub, can't do anything about it from my side ;)

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Abug+wrong+position ;)